# ORA-00904, Code Newbie I need help in identifying what's wrong

Tags: sql, oracle

```
CREATE TABLE TASK_SKILL (TASK_ID INT REFERENCES PROJECT_SCHEDULE_TASK(TASK_ID),
                SKILL_ID INT REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
                NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (TASK_ID, PROJECT_ID, SKILL_ID));
```

Good day, I know my questions seem to be quite newbie-ish and is common sense for most of you here, but I am still trying to learn SQL

I encountered "ORA-00904: "PROJECT_ID": invalid identifier".

I have already checked and it looks like I have a Project_ID column but still, I can't seem to run it.

Comment: You don't have a `PROJECT_ID` column declared for this table

Comment: The tag `sql` says: "...and a tag for the DBMS implementation (e.g. MySQL, PostgreSQL, Oracle, MS SQL Server, IBM DB2, etc.) being used." **Please correct the tags**

Comment: One issue is your caps lock is on :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a table TASK_SKILL with 3 fiels: TASK_ID, SKILL_ID and NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES. Also you want to create a Primary Key by TASK_ID, PROJECT_ID, SKILL_ID. Oracle is right, you do not have a PROJECT_ID field in your table.
Your field is called SKILL_ID, so the Primary key should be created using it, like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TASK_SKILL (TASK_ID INT REFERENCES PROJECT_SCHEDULE_TASK(TASK_ID),
                SKILL_ID INT REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
                NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (TASK_ID, SKILL_ID));
```

In the PK of a table you ony include fields from the table and not field from the related table. So, no need to include te referenced PROJECT_ID.

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are trying to create a table with a column that doesn't exist, in this case, `PROJECT_ID`. In the `TASK_SKILL` Table you only have 3 Columns defined:

1. `TASK_ID`, which is a foreign key of the `PROJECT_SCHEDULE_TASK` table
2. `SKILL_ID`, which is a foreign key of the `PROJECT` table.
3. `NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES`  which is an integer.

Try to create the table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE TASK_SKILL (TASK_ID INT REFERENCES PROJECT_SCHEDULE_TASK(TASK_ID),
                SKILL_ID INT REFERENCES PROJECT(PROJECT_ID),
                NUMBER_OF_EMPLOYEES INT,
                PRIMARY KEY (TASK_ID, SKILL_ID));
```

Lastly, if you're just starting out learning SQL, you can first lay the foundations of database design before going hands-on.

[oracle documentation of foreign keys](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17952_01/mysql-5.6-en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)